# Inconsistent output format of Postgres query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm querying a Postgres database for 3 varchar(n) fields like follows:

```
Select ("Title","Author","Isbn") from public."Book" Where 1=1
```

The output of the query is a tuple with 3 strings. However the formatting of output is sometimes inconsistent between records. Note the output of the query:

[image]

Notice the difference in the first element between row 40 and row 41/42. The first element of row 40 is "Revolutionary Road" (wrapped in double quotes). The first element of row 41 is Neuromancer (not wrapped in quotes). The same phenomena occurs elsewhere in the query set as well.

I'm not sure why this first element is sometimes inconsistent in how it's returned by the query. It's not an issue with the individual records themselves. What else might be wrong?

Comment: Remove the parentheses around the columns. Why did you add them anyway?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no reason specifically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result is correct. In this output format, Postgres use quotes when string has spaces or some special chars:

```
postgres=# select row('ahoj', 'ahoj svete', 'ahoj,svete', '"ahoj svete"');
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                        row                        │
╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│ (ahoj,"ahoj svete","ahoj,svete","""ahoj svete""") │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

If you don't want output format of composite value, don't use a `row` constructor:

```
postgres=# select 'ahoj', 'ahoj svete', 'ahoj,svete', '"ahoj svete"';
┌──────────┬────────────┬────────────┬──────────────┐
│ ?column? │  ?column?  │  ?column?  │   ?column?   │
╞══════════╪════════════╪════════════╪══════════════╡
│ ahoj     │ ahoj svete │ ahoj,svete │ "ahoj svete" │
└──────────┴────────────┴────────────┴──────────────┘
(1 row)
```

Comment: Ohhh the parentheses that i wrapped the columns around actually changes the query. That makes sense. Thank you!